# debugging inside groovy closure in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am running Eclipse Neon with [groovy plugin](http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.6/).

I am not able to evaluate variables inside closures in debug mode. I tried in adding those variables in Expressions windows, also in Display window, but no use. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this error a couple of times, though they didn't happened all the time. Right now, I tested this and it worked, even with nested closures. I'm on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, JDK 1.6.0_45, Groovy 2.3.10.

Comment: I mostly see these errors...barely able to debug inside closures

Comment: IIRC, there is some variable which encapsulates the other vars. Try going to Eclipse's Variables view and expand the variables there.

Comment: yes in variables view they are getting evaluated, but sometimes I want to evaluate complex expressions involving variables not just plain variables

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I also can't evaluate expressions nor Display them. IIRC, this never worked... I'm not sure why. Perhaps due to dynamic class generation with closures, or eclipse is trying to evaluate expressions using its own Java engine, whilst Groovy needs stuff to get going through the MOP.

Comment: glad to know I am not alone with "this never worked"...but would be awesome if this starts working, may be somehow magically...

Comment: btw earlier I had issue with ggts too...but it was giving different error explanation. I sneaked inside eclipse logs which gave me detailed explanation, though I was not able to fix it. Here is that [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093337/unable-to-add-watch-expressions-in-eclipse).

Comment: Were you ever able to debug (use Display, Expressions window) inside closures?